# Passing the name of a table cell to detailed view

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, sdk

How would I be able to pass the name of a table cell that is clicked in a Master View Controller to a Detailed View Controller. I would like it to be used later in my detailed view right now though I would like to use this data for the detailed view's navigation item title by means of `self.navigationItem.title =`. Can anyone please provide basic code to how to make this happen?

Comment: Ok I have table cells in my master view so when a user selects a cell it takes them to a detailed view. In this detailed view there is a navigation item. I would like the navigation item's title to be the name of the cell the user selected.

Comment: I guess you can give it in didselectrow delgate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your going to want to use the `didselectrowatindexpath` method.  Something like this, initialize the new view and set the title:

```
    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
        DetailViewController *myDetViewCont = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

        NSInteger row = indexPath.row;
        NSString *title = [ListOfItems objectAtIndex:row];

        myDetViewCont.navigationItem.title = title;
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:myDetViewCont animated:YES];

    }
```

Comment: could you emphasize more on arrayOfTitles my array looks like   `listOfItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    
    //Add items
    [listOfItems addObject:@"Case"];`

Comment: Also I have a NSMuttableArray

Comment: I edited to match what I think you are going for(let me know). Is this `listOfItems` contain the titles that you wish to display in the detail views? And are they in the same order as the tableViewCells?

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to set the navigation title, you can just set it before you push the detailViewController in navigation controllers' stack.

```
detailViewController.title = @"whatever you want";
```

If you do need the name of the cell for other places, then make a `NSString` property in DetailViewController, and set it before pushing.

Answer (score 0):

The easy way is to create a property in the detailed view controller and set it to the title. Then you can use in the ViewDidLoad to set the title.

psuedo code:

- create detailed view controller
- set property
- push it on the navigation bar
- grab property in ViewDidLoad